# Удаление скобок в предложении

Tags: c#

Дано выражение: ((FvG)^(FvH)). Необходимо удалить скобки начиная со внутренних и заканчивая внешними. После первой итерации должно получиться (FvG^FvH) и потом уже FvG^FvH

Не могу понять как найти сами внутренние скобки, чтобы цикл продолжался.

Comment: Есть простой алгоритм проверки корректности скобок, то есть когда каждая открывающая имеет следом закрывающую, легко сможете его найти. На его базе текущую задачу решить проще простого. И я не понял, нужно скобки удалить или какие-то итерации куда-то выводить? Зачем, какой именно требуется результат? Как проверить корректность выполненного решения? Покажите код, который написали пытаясь решить задачу.

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы на каждой итерации удалялись скобки. На 1- внутренние и на 2 -  внешние.

Comment: Так если в итоге будут удалены все скобки, то зачем эти итерации, просто вырезать символы скобок из строки, и готово. Результат одинаковый.

Comment: У меня в цикле также есть замена символов в строке после удаление скобок. На первой итерации у меня заменяется вместо правых скобок операторы внутри скобок. То есть (FGv^FHv). И в конце уже получается FGvFHv^

Comment: Я 2 раза задал один и тот же вопрос, вы 0 раз на него ответили. Еще раз: код вставьте в вопрос, и объясните чем вам обычный `Replace` не угодил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sb = new StringBuilder("((FvG)^(FvH))");
Console.WriteLine(sb);

var indexes = new List<(int, int)>();

while (true)
{
    int start = -1;
    int end = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < sb.Length; i++)
    {
        if (sb[i] == '(')
        {
            start = i;
        }
        if (sb[i] == ')' && start != -1)
        {
            end = i;
            indexes.Add((start, end));
            start = -1;
        }
    }

    if (indexes.Count == 0)
        break;

    for (int i = indexes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        (start, end) = indexes[i];

        // Здесь можно вставить какую-то логику для обработки значений между скобками
        // string value = s.ToString(start + 1, end - start - 1);

        sb.Remove(end, 1);
        sb.Remove(start, 1);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(sb);

    indexes.Clear();
}
```